# Advanced English: What can be "rather than a subtle ______ " in movies?

Tags: single-word-requests, collocation, cinema

I have this book, donkey's years old—1991—called *Cambridge Advanced English*, written by Leo Jones. The topic of *films, shows, and concerts* is dealt with in chapter 3 but there's a problem, it's a student's book without answers, and there is no list where students can select answers from. Moreover, I gave it as homework to a private student of mine who's coming tomorrow. I have worked out all the answers (in capital letters) except for this particular one:

> 3. Horror films like *A Nightmare on Elm Street* depend on spectacular SPECIAL effects rather than a subtle ___________.

It's driving me potty, I want to say *dialogue*, but can dialogue be *subtle*? The term *screenplay* was one of the answers, so it can't be that. No term can be used more than twice.

> 4. *Superman 2*, DIRECTED by Richard Lester, was the SEQUEL to Superman the SCREENPLAY was co-written by Mario Puzo, who wrote the *The Godfather*.

Below are answers which I cannot reuse with "subtle"

> 5. A really exciting movie depends on good LIGHTING (photography), good EDITING (the way the film is cut with perfect timing so that each  SHOT surprises you), and exciting STUNTS (car chases, fights and falls).
> 6. It was hard to follow the PLOT because there were so many FLASHBACKS to scenes that had happened earlier

I'm not 100% convinced by LIGHTING, is that the right term to use here? Is there a better one? Regardless, the one really bugging me is **Q.3**, it goes without saying, the term must be related to films/movies.

[image]

List of terms, in italics, which I have already used: *game* (shows); *soap* (operas); (crime) *series*; *full*-(length) *animated* (film); *produced* (by), *special* (effects); **(a subtle) _____** ; directed (by); sequel (to); screenplay (was co-written); (good) *lighting*; (good) *editing*; (each) *shot*; (exciting) *stunts*; ([a Dolby stereo) *sound system*](https://www.thefreelibrary.com/Matchstick+Marvels-a0148186794); (the) *technology / facilities* (to take advantage of this); (sub-)*titles*; (may be) *dubbed*; (played the) *role*; *co* (-star); (Jack Nicholson) *stole* (every scene); (Italian-American) *co-production*; (shot on) *location*; (received a lot of) *Academy Awards/Oscars*; (was) *overrated*; (follow the) *plot*; *flashbacks* (to scenes); (the names of the stars and the) *film / producers*; (opening) *credits*; (complete) *cast* (of characters);  *played* (them); (film) *crew*; (all the) *extras*; (new) *production* (by); *sets* (were designed).

Q. What can be inserted after ‘a subtle’ to contrast with ‘spectacular special effects’?

Comment: _Why_ can't 'plot' be re-used? Or the (near-) synonym 'storyline'?

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth because the point of the task is to test one's knowledge of showbusiness / movie vocabulary

Comment: Is there any reason why 'storyline' (qv) doesn't work?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Thank you for the edit, the question is now much better.

Comment: I don't know what your can reuse or not, but if you need to rely on special effects then your plot is weak. Perhaps a synonym like *story* or *screenplay*?

Comment: Why didn't _I_ fix it? / Yes, but far too few are. Check the standard of examples on the internet rather than the number.

Comment: I'm struggling not to close-vote a question asking 'What showbusiness- / movie-related word, not including A/B/ ... /Y, fits sensibly into the sentence 'Horror films like A Nightmare on Elm Street depend on spectacular SPECIAL effects rather than a subtle ___________.'? How does this benefit the general audience? Isn't the site Xanne suggests a more appropriate site to ask this on?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Do you think this question is off-topic for a website about the English language? I supplied research/answers, I provided context, the exercise comes from an English language book, advanced level, I've explained why the same word cannot be used twice, and I'm also asking for a little help from my "friends". The indefinite article in "a subtle" makes the question also more interesting and useful, in my view. You are free to disagree of course.

Comment: @HotLicks do you think "than a subtle lighting" works in this particular context?

Comment: I'm now convinced it's off-topic for ELU. But _of course_ it would be acceptable on some other English websites. In essence, it's a single word request: W must (1) be connected with the film industry / show business; (2) not be any of the following; (3) contrast sensibly with 'depend on spectacular SPECIAL effects rather than ...'; (4) fit grammatically into this frame. How many people is this going to be of use to?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is too narrowly scoped.

Comment: You may like to consider *atmosphere* as in  '...depend on (spectacular special effects) rather than *a subtle* **atmosphere**'  based on this definition: "atmosphere: refers to any concrete or nebulous quality or feeling that contributes a dimensional tone to a film's action. Examples: spookiness, howling wind, searing heat, blinding light, a rain downpour, etc." Source: http://www.filmsite.org/filmterms2.html

Comment: @EnglishStudent thanks but "a **subtle** *atmosphere*" in a horror movie fits less well. I am convinced the best answer is *soundtrack*, it's not used elsewhere in the exercise and it's a very common term used in the movie industry. native speakers are familiar with its meaning. On the other hand,  "depends on good cinematography" is, I believe,  a better suggestion than "depends on good lighting"

Comment: @EnglishStudent really good link though, thanks a lot!

Comment: You are welcome! Soundtrack is certainly a good choice, being a good fit for 'a subtle', but words like cinematography, lighting, dialogues etc work better with 'subtle' than '**a subtle**'. Looking through the glossary of movie-making terms in that link might give you other suitable options.

Comment: If you are not fully satisfied with 'soundtrack', you might further consider words like 'a subtle story-line', 'a subtle narration' 'a subtle presentation' or even 'a subtle development (of suspense)' because the thrust of the statement seems to be that such horror movies depend on over-the-top special effects rather than a more subtle cinematic approach to presenting the horror story (of which the **soundtrack** is certainly an important part!)

Comment: @EnglishStudent I am fully satisfied with *soundtrack* what makes you feel I'm not? Where did I say that? However, if you don't believe it's the best term, please post your solution. You  should hurry though, there are two votes in favour of closing this question.

Comment: 1.You can go with 'soundtrack' if you are satisfied. IT FITS THE SENTENCE WELL. I am personally not fully satisfied with 'a subtle soundtrack' only because I don't think it is the best contrast in meaning to 'spectacular special effects' - I interpret the statement as 'spectacular effects rather than a subtle cinematic presentation / approach' but can't give a *single word* (especially a cinematic term) that fits the case, my possibilities being 'a more subtle development of suspense', 'a  subtle and creepy escalation of horror' etc. **2.my unofficial vote: am NOT in favor of closing this Q!**

Comment: I like this question, and am amazed that it is stalled at +2/-2.  (Only one  person other  than me upvoted it ??!!)  The challenge of finding a word in a particular field makes it harder but no less relevant than a less constricted question.  The phrase that popped into my mind -- "subtle creepiness" is, I'm sure, not what you are looking for, but it seems to fit the early and mid stages of "Get Out".

Comment: FWIW, Amazon.com is selling a [used copy of the teacher's book](https://smile.amazon.com/Cambridge-Advanced-English-Teachers-book/dp/0521336988/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1494867641&sr=8-1&keywords=0521336988) for under $5

Comment: @AC  with shipping and handling costs it's going to cost me 20.05 euros, Eeek! I'll need to think about it... but I just might order it.  *Estimated delivery:  June 16, 2017 - July 19, 2017* :-) Thank you for finding it!

Comment: The sellers on the US Amazon are in UK, France, Germany, Japan, and Canada.  Perhaps your local flavor of Amazon (or other bookseller) would be a little cheaper.  ISBN 0521336988 / 978-0521336987 .  

More importantly, please let us know what the author suggests, if you ever find out!  I'm almost annoyed enough to want to chip in on a copy.

Comment: [This page](https://quizlet.com/22990645/tzs-doga-3-mondatbefejezesek-flash-cards/) seems to indicate that the correct answer is special effects / subtle plot (as others have suggested).  It's not exactly a reputable looking source, but hopefully they at least plagiarized from the solution manual.

Comment: @AC annoyed? Oh dear, do you think *soundtrack* is misplaced? When I have the time, I'll see if I can find the book in Amazon Germany or UK. Anyway, thanks for taking an interest.

Comment: @AC Oh, I think you should post an answer. *Good camera work*, is actually spot on and... it's Dolby stereo soundtrack...argghhh! Foiled.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm guessing that the Cambridge Advanced English Teacher's Book (ISBN-13: 978-0521336987, ISBN-10: 0521336988) will offer a definitive answer.  It seems that there are some [used copies](https://smile.amazon.com/Cambridge-Advanced-English-Teachers-book/dp/0521336988/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1494867641&sr=8-1&keywords=0521336988) available online.

I've also found a site ([here](https://quizlet.com/22990645/tzs-doga-3-mondatbefejezesek-flash-cards/)) which appears to have "borrowed heavily" from these books.  The questions listed match those in the Student's Book -- if the answers that are listed came from the Teacher's Book, then the author intended:

> 3. Horror films like A Nightmare on Elm Street depend on spectacular `special` effects rather than a subtle `plot`.
> 4. Superman 2, `directed` by Richard Lester, was the `sequel` to Superman. The `script` was co-written by Mario Puzo, who wrote The
>      Godfather.
> 5. A really exciting movie depends on good `camerawork`, good `editing` (the way the film is cut with perfect timing so that each
>      `scene` surprises you) and exciting `stunts`.
> 6. Modern films have a Dolby stereo `soundtrack` but not all cinemas have the `equipment` to take advantage of this.
>
> ...
>
> 10. It was hard to follow the `plot` because there were so many `flashbacks` to scenes that had happened earlier.

Comment: Good find! But does that mean that **plot** is used twice, *contra* the apparent directions?

Comment: These answers are probably *not* the "official" ones - at least not all of them. For example, #2 should be: "*Snow White and the Seven Dwarfs* was the first `feature`-length `animated` film" - not "`cartoon` film". Still, ...

Comment: @michael.hor257k I believe that at the time, they *were* animated cartoon films, having evolved from "static" drawn cartoons into animated cartoon shorts, and finally a feature-length cartoon film.  I do agree that I would certainly say "animated film" these days, but if anything "cartoon film" is more specific, as animation encompasses other techniques such as stop-motion.  This ["ancient" article](http://www.animatormag.com/archive/issue-20/issue-20-page-20/) seems to be pretty comfortable with both terms.  Maybe we should start a gofundme to send a teacher's copy to the OP?

Comment: @AC What do you mean by "at that time"? The book was first published in 1991. And 1987 is not "ancient". The vocabulary was the same then as it is now. -- P.S. The article you cite seems to be comfortable with a lot of informal/jargon words, e.g. *talkies*. When it switches to a formal tone, it says clearly "*a feature-length animated film*" (para 3).

Comment: @michael.hor257k I meant in 1937, when the term "cartoon films" would have been describing a literal reel of film with an animated cartoon on it. I only mentioned the 1987 article because it's a lot closer to being contemporary with the 1991 book than we are today, and that was a very formative period for Western animation. (And yes, I know 1987 isn't *really* ancient, hence the quotes.  Kidding aside, it IS pretty old for an internet find -- IIRC in '87 I was using pre-internet BBS systems).  Anyway, just saying that I can believe it WAS the intended answer, though today I would prefer yours.

Comment: @AC I believe the purpose of the book is to teach *contemporary* English. I don't see how 1937 terms are relevant to that purpose.

Comment: @michael.hor257k I'm just saying that the term might have been more common in 1991 British English than it is in 2017.  [See ngram.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=cartoon+film%2Canimated+film&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=6&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccartoon%20film%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Canimated%20film%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: @AC I am old enough to know it wasn't, though not British enough to extend that claim to BrE with full confidence. But I suspect that if you examine the actual use cases, you will find that most if not all of them are informal.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58851/discussion-between-a-c-and-michael-hor257k).

Comment: @AC Some other time perhaps. I've already spent too much time on this page.

Comment: You and me both, LOL.  For what it's worth, the author does use the term "cartoon film" in the [newer edition of the student's book](https://books.google.com/books?id=f32lBWccBsYC&lpg=PP1&pg=PA188#v=onepage&q=film&f=false) (p. 188) as well.

Answer (score 5):

Here's my answer, revised and reposted.

What @Scotty Colby might have meant was good **[cinematography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cinematography)**.

> A really exciting movie depends on good **CINEMATOGRAPHY** (photography), good
>   EDITING (the way the film is cut with perfect timing so that each SHOT
>   surprises you), and exciting STUNTS (car chases, fights and falls).

IMO, *lighting* is not a synonym for *photography*. *Cinematography*, on the other hand, is.

Someone who's in charge of *lighting* won't be fiddling around with how that ligthning will be depicted on the actual film, the way a [cinematographer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cinematographer) will.

Then, you sentence might indeed be:

*Horror films like A Nightmare on Elm Street depend on spectacular SPECIAL effects rather than a **subtle lighting*** (speaking [of a mixture or effect delicately complex and understated](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/subtle)).

Comment: "...depends on **a** subtle lighting..." Can we say this? Without the indefinite article, it works much better.

Comment: @Mari-Lou A There has been a thread which addressed the use of a/an with non-count nouns (search for 'sunlight'). It is not ungrammatical / unidiomatic per se (a subtle light filtered through the trees) but it doesn't work here.

Comment: The link contains some nice visual explanation of what constitutes "[good cinematography](http://imgur.com/a/XrapY)" Many thanks for resolving that particular dilemma.  +1 for Scott Colby and your answers.

Comment: Yes to *cinematography*, but No to *a subtle lighting*. The rest of the exercise looks like it lives up to the label "advanced English", but *a subtle lighting* is neither generally idiomatic nor a specialized Hollywood term.

Answer (score 4):

I think I have it.

> Horror films like A Nightmare on Elm Street depend on spectacular SPECIAL (or VISUAL) effects rather than a subtle **SOUNDTRACK**.

Music in horror films help create mood, tension, and suspense. A *subtle* soundtrack, which also includes sound effects and narration, would not rely on shrills, screams, or melodramatic musical scores to create a sense of impending doom. On the contrary, less is more, as Janus Bahs Jacquet mentions in the comments below.

According to Cambridge Dictionaries, the term *soundtrack* is countable, and it means:

> **[soundtrack](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/soundtrack)**
>   noun [ C ]
>   the sounds, especially the music, of a film, or a separate recording of this:
>   - *The best thing about the movie is its soundtrack.*

- [Horror Movie Soundtracks](http://www.amc.com/movie-guide/best-horror-movie-soundtracks)
- [The 100 greatest horror soundtracks](http://www.factmag.com/2014/10/28/the-100-greatest-horror-soundtracks/)

Lastly I checked the collocation, there aren't many written instances of "subtle soundtrack" on the Internet, but I did find these two instances

> **A "subtle" soundtrack makes audiences rise**
>
> With so many special effects and dramatic moments the Batman trilogy has become known for, fans might not notice the one thing that ties it all together: the music.
>
> “A good film composer will enhance the dramatic message of the film,” said Harry Bulow, head of the School of Visual and Performing Arts. “After you watch a two-hour film you say, ‘Wow, that went by fast!’ That’s what you want.”
>
> Source: [The Exponent](http://www.purdueexponent.org/features/article_ec220dc3-eaed-57fc-b3fe-a0df59433ce6.html); Jul 20, 2012

and a review mentioning the music in *Alien*

> This **soundtrack** is all about suspense. The movie it accompanies is a very slow build in true 70s fashion, and the music moves at a similar pace. […]
>
> The highlight of the score is the main theme, again edited heavily from the composer’s original intention to be far more **subtle** and ominous for the titles, but then settles to a simple melodic passage of lone brass. It is a soft, melodic piece of music that speaks of the void and loneliness of space. It is this initial pace of the film and the soundtrack that makes the later half so terrifying even when the soundtrack starts to evaporate to a more modern, stark, harsh reality…of everyone being munched by an alien.
>
> Source: [Sabotage Times](http://sabotagetimes.com/music/gengahr-favourite-horror-soundtracks)

Comment: I was just about to suggest that—I just saw the picture from the book now, and _soundtrack_ was the first thing that came to mind. The subtleness of horror soundtracks in particular is that at the most tense and crucial moments, _there is often little or no music at all_. The technique of simple silence is indeed a very subtle way of hinting at horror-shock scenes. I'm not sure _special effects_ is necessarily the best option, though: to contrast with _soundtrack_, I would probably go with _visual effects_ instead.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Thanks. It came to me in a light-bulb moment. Could you do me a favour? What says you about "good cinematography" and "good lighting" which fits better in your opinion?

Comment: I doubt very much that is the correct answer. Special effects are visual, a soundtrack is auditory. I don't think anyone ever said in a production meeting: "Let's dump the subtle soundtrack and invest in spectacular special effects instead".

Comment: @michael.hor257k That's not the intended meaning of the sentence. It is supposed to say that unlike some horror movies (like _Paranormal Activity_), which rely very heavily on the subtleties of the soundtrack and only occasionally employ advanced special visual effects to create tension, films like _Nightmare on Elm Street_ are the opposite: they draw heavily on special effects and don't rely nearly as much on sound cues.

Comment: @Mari-LouA _Cinematography_ fits better with the ‘clue’, I think, but both are reasonable.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet No, the intended meaning of the sentence is that some movies attract audiences by visuals, and some by the story. No film's selling point is its subtle soundtrack.

Comment: @michael.hor257k That seems exceedingly unlikely. Very, very few horror films’ selling point is a subtle plot. Not many have special effects as their selling point either. The selling point of all horror films is that particular horror atmosphere, and this is not about main selling plots or attracting audiences, but techniques used to create that atmosphere. Had the example been “Some large-scale productions like _Avatar_”, then the juxtaposition of plot and special effects would have been a good bet, but not here.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet The sentence does not compare two kinds of horror films. It compares horror films to other genres.

Comment: @michael.hor257k And your basis for that claim is..? There is absolutely no way to conclude that from the sentence given.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Don't go there.

Comment: @michael.hor257k You have no basis for the claim because there is none. You are stating your own interpretation as undeniable fact. It is not.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I was expressing my opinion, as you were yours. And now you're being rude.

Comment: I think if you contrast *visual* effects with the score or soundtrack as @JanusBahsJacquet suggests, this makes sense. *Visual* makes more sense than *special* for horror movies, anyway, since effects aren't necessarily very high tech (especially back in 1991); they often run more towards just fake blood and gory makeup.

Comment: @1006a *visual effects* is a good solution, and I will also mention it to my private student, but I feel that "special effects" compared to "visual effects" has the upperhand. And Ngram seems to suggest that the expression SFX was familiar in the US 
 during the 1990s https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=special+effects%2C+visual+effects&year_start=1930&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cspecial%20effects%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cvisual%20effects%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Special effects and SFX are certainly more common for film in general. I just don't think they make as much sense for old-school horror flicks. The original *Nightmare*, for example, had a famously tiny budget but spectacular makeup. Google returns about twice as many examples of the phrase "a nightmare on elm street visual effects" as "a nightmare on elm street special effects" when I search.

Comment: @1006a special effects does not exclude (special) makeup, sound, light, or photography. I'm happy with both expressions, they are both suitable. I'm less happy with getting downvoted though.

Comment: I upvoted your answer, so I doubt visual vs special is the issue.

Comment: BTW, if terms cannot be reused, then you have another problem because the correct answer to #6 is most certainly *Modern films have a Dolby stereo **soundtrack*** (not ***system***, as you wrote).

Comment: @michael.hor257k The answer for No.3 remains *soundtrack*. There's [*Dolby stereo sound/surround*](https://www.nfsa.gov.au/preservation/preservation-glossary/dolby-stereo-sound), and [*Dolby stereo noise-reduction system*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dolby_noise-reduction_system) I forgot the NR bit, so thanks for making me look up the precise term.

Comment: A film does not have a system. It has a soundtrack (that may use a specific system of noise reduction). -- P.S. I don't intend to argue about this. I recommend you find the companion book and lookup the answers given there.

Comment: @michael.hor257k you seem to be the argumentative one here. "Dolby stereo sound/surround" works fine here. I looked online for the 1991/2 teacher's book before coming here, I couldn't find it. I found a pdf file of the student's book, which is of no use. I'm open minded enough to check things two, three times before reaching a conclusion. Perhaps you should do likewise, the supporting evidence for "subtle soundtrack" is in my answer. I don't have any problems admitting when I'm wrong, but on this (no.3) I am 100% convinced.

Answer (score 3):

For Q5, I might say that "a really exciting movie depends on good <s>*filmography*</s> *[cinematography](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cinematography)* (photography)..." rather than "lighting." (Here, I'm using "cinematography" in the second sense listed in the linked source.)

Q3 poses difficulty to me, too. Perhaps "mise-en-scene" fits the bill? The sentence is so general, though, that I would not fault even a professional filmmaker who couldn't choose what the author thought was correct. In the worst case, you could grade your student on her ability to explain why her answer would be appropriate or why she couldn't find a perfect fit, just as you have here.

Comment: I've just been checking as well and I agree that the sense I seem to be using is not supported. See my edit (will be made momentarily) for an alternative.

Comment: Answer withdrawn. Comment added instead. This does seem like the way to go. Check Wikipedia's article on [cinematography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cinematography) for further info. Then, your sentence might indeed be: *Horror films like A Nightmare on Elm Street depend on spectacular SPECIAL effects rather than a subtle lightning* (speaking [of a mixture or effect delicately complex and understated](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/subtle)).

Comment: I agree with @m.a.a.'s view on using "subtle lighting" in Q3 as a contrast to special effects, now that lighting has been freed up by switching to cinematography in Q5.

Comment: @m.a.a. my main question is about *subtle* ____. "good lighting" is acceptable to my mind, I don't think it's wrong, I was just slightly concerned, niggled, not 100% convinced but "subtle lighting" does fit. But how would that relate to horror films? Scott's answer has mise-en-scene, which doesn't fit.

Comment: @Mari-LouA to me, "lighting" does not equate with the hint of "photography." That may be my own bias as a theatre lighting designer, however...

Comment: Is "lighting" countable though? "... **a** subtle lighting..."? Can you say this?

Comment: A subtle theme?  a subtle development of character?

Comment: Also--a subtle drama or story line.

Comment: Anyway--some students have done this before.  https://groups.yahoo.com/neo/groups/EngFor/conversations/topics/3085  I think _list_ should be _cast_ ; stars and title are given in the opening scene.